# 'True bypass' pedal doesn't allow signal to pass through when turned off

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, equipment

I've never really messed with guitar pedals so I'm a little confused. I just got the Hall of Fame Reverb pedal of TC and it says true bypass on it. When the pedal is off, I don't hear anything from the amp. Does this mean if that pedals is gonna be in line with others, it has to be on the whole time?

Comment: That doesn't sound like the pedal is working right - the HoF has two bypass modes, both of which should pass dry signal when the pedal is off. There is also a kill-dry mode, which will stop your dry sound, but that comes into play when the pedal is *on*. When you say 'off', is the pedal still *powered*?

Comment: And just to check - the pedal is working fine when it's on?

Comment: Also, make sure you're plugged into the **mono** input and the **mono** output of the pedal.

Comment: Yeah i was plugged into the mono on both sides, yet when i would active the foot switch everything would be fine and the moment i turned the pedal off i couldn't hear my guitar through the amp at all. Maybe something is wrong with the pedal.

Answer (score 3):

There must be something wrong with the pedal. The indication 'true bypass' means that when the pedal is connected with the guitar and amp and is turned off, the signal will pass directly to the amp.

> With a true bypass pedal, when the pedal is in bypass mode (off), the guitar signal is routed directly to the guitar amplifier without any of the interference, loading, or buffering effects that are often caused by the pedals that are in-between.
>
> [source](http://thehub.musiciansfriend.com/tech-tips/tech-tip-true-bypass-pedals-and-buffers)

If you have it turned off, you should hear your guitar cleanly. If you do not, there must be something wrong with the pedal.

Just make sure that everything else works correctly:

- The cables
- The guitar
- The amp
- The pedal (when it's turned on)
- If you have multiple pedals, make sure all of the cables are connected correctly and are all the way in.

If all of these work correctly, then something in the pedal is not working as it should. Take it to a technician or to the store if it has warranty.

Comment: Note that with the Hall of Fame pedal, 'True Bypass' or 'Buffered Bypass' can be selected.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. It must be the pedal because my other pedals in the line work perfectly fine. Such a bummer considering its brand new.

Comment: If it's brand new take it back to where you bought it and have it changed. Or get a refund. If it's new, it *has* to work correctly